# Getting error when i run a npm command in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am watching a Udemy tutorial on Node, React, Express. When i run the command

```
        npm run data:import
```

i have this error:

```
        undefined
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! myfolder@1.0.0 data:import: `node back-end/seeder`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the myfolder@1.0.0 data:import script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR! C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-04T09_05_34_700Z-debug.log
```

I have the same code with the guy in the tutorial but i have this error. The code is shown below:

```
const importData = async () => {
  try {
    await Order.deleteMany()
    await Product.deleteMany()
    await User.deleteMany()

    const createdUsers = await User.insertMany(users)

    const adminUser = createdUsers[0]._id

    const sampleProducts = products.map(product => {
        return {...product, user: adminUser}
    })

    await Product.insertMany(sampleProducts)

    console.log('Data Imported!!'.green)
    process.exit()
  } catch (error){
    console.error(`${error}`.red)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}
```

I have seen similar questions but i have to uninstall the npm and delete the nodemodules and then re-install the npm. Is there any other way to solve my problem without doing the above process.

When i run another npm command like

```
 npm start
```

I don't have the above problem

Comment: What's the tutorial? You can add breakpoints in your code to see where the error appears.

Comment: The file `2021-08-04T09_05_34_700Z-debug.log` that it mentions might give more info.  Unfortunately the npm Error seems to be lacking anything useful here.

Comment: @Keith Do you want to provide you that file?

Comment: @Andy the tutorial called Mern ecommerce from Scratch

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a package.json file, if you don't then run npm init and press enter untill it's finished. After that add the npm packages that are needed with 'npm install <package_name>' and then it will work.

If you have package.json file, delete your node_modules and run npm install again.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve my problem without doing that procedure

Comment: Well not really that i know. You don't have to reinstall 'npm' you just have to delete node_modules and install them again. Good luck!